# UFT - AUT is a web application and UFT is not recogning the webtable rowcount at runtime after deleting rows

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

The `rowcount` remains constant, which means the `Do` Loop is never exited.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
Do
    a = Browser(browser).Page(page).WebTable("webtable").RowCount
    noOfRows = a - 1
    Browser(browser).Page(page).Link("Delete").Click
Loop While noOfRows > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check with for loop as follows

```
Dim iCount 
sRow = Browser(browser).Page(page).WebTable("webtable").RowCount
for iCount = 0 To sRow-1
        Browser(browser).Page(page).Link("Delete").Click
Next
```

It will first find no of rows on page and For loop is use to delete them.